# How to send Intent to SMS Receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I would like a send an intent to this receiver from another application, which handles SMS. I am quite new to this SMS handling. Can someone kindly guide me on what intent,I mean, how and what and intent should have to execute this piece of receiver code. Thanks.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        try {
            Object[] objArr = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                SmsMessage createFromPdu = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) obj);
                String displayOriginatingAddress = createFromPdu.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String displayMessageBody = createFromPdu.getDisplayMessageBody();
                try {
                    if (displayOriginatingAddress.contains("MADAPP")) {
                        if (displayMessageBody.contains("The PIN is")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, displayMessageBody, 1).show();

                        }
                        if (displayMessageBody.contains("successfully validated")) {
                            displayMessageBody.contains("activating Pockets");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Send an SMS to the device/emulator the app is on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

write this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
  <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

For more description

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But if i want to trigger this piece of code from other application, what should i do?

Comment: you can set your custom action which will be recieved by this broadcast reciever. for ex. `<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="custom.action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`   You can go through this link for more details https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/